# How to retry process with while loop in python?

Tags: python, while-loop

```
try:
link = input("Enter URL: ")
yt = YouTube(link)
downloadvideo = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
downloadvideo.download()
```

except:
# I want to retry it with while loop

Comment: Well then, put it in a `while` loop.  What's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```py
while True:
  try:
    link = input("Enter URL: ")
    yt = YouTube(link)
    downloadvideo = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
    downloadvideo.download()
    break
  except:
    ...
```

The break statment breaks the loop is the try statment is successful.